# Change color of googleMaps current location icon/marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using googleMapsApi in a swift project. I was wondering if it is possible to change the color of the marker or icon that shows the users current location. I understand how to add a custom marker with images, colors, shapes etc.. but the default current location marker that is blue can I change to be red or any other color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no official way to replace the blue current location dot in `GMSMapView`.

The only way to achieve this is by removing the blue dot by setting `mapView.myLocationEnabled` to `false` and then create a custom `GMSMarker` with the design you want and place it on the current location position on the map.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is unfortunate but not at all devastating.